# Javascript Syntax Error when Assigning Razor variable to a Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Very strange behavior that I could not understand where the razor variable completely disappears as seen in the screenshot (@SomeID disappears). My goal is to get the id from the server, then assign it to a javascript variable. The problem appears to happen when the razor variable is null and also no matter where I assign this variable even with document ready.

The View:

```
@{
long? SomeID= (long?)ViewBag.BoxID;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
var testVariable;

function OnElementLoaded() {
    testVariable = @SomeID; 
}     
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: don't dump data directly into a JS context. as you see, it's very easy to generate JS syntax errors, which then kill the entire JS code block. always output via json, which will handle the translation from native->js for you, including any necessary quoting/escaping.

Comment: @MarcB, could you please clarify about the benefit of json in this situation. I already send the data wrapped in a model that has a c# type.

Comment: in your case, it's a long value, so not a big deal. but consider a string. `foo = "Miles O'brien";`, and then dump that into js: `testVar = Miles O'Brien;`. now you've got an undefined variable (`Miles`) and a flat-out syntax error with an unexpected extra undefined variable (`O`) followed by an unterminated string `'Brien`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asssuming `SomeID` variable has some value like `2545` in it. Razor will render your code like below.

```
testVariable = 2545;
```

But your variable is nullable type. That means it could have a `null` value. I believe your `ViewBag.BoxID` value is null, hence your variable became null and your resulting HTML became,

```
function OnElementLoaded() {
    testVariable = ;
}
```

One thing you can do is to wrap the value in  quotes. But this works best for non numeric values(strings).

```
function OnElementLoaded() {
    testVariable = `@SomeID`; 
}
```

For numeric values, It is best do a null check and assign value. If the value of your c# expression is null, set to 0 ( or any default value you want);

For example, the below code will set 0 if the `ViewBag.BoxID` expression returns null.

```
@{
    long? SomeID = ViewBag.BoxID!=null ? (long?)ViewBag.BoxID:0;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var testVariable;

    function OnElementLoaded() {
        testVariable = @SomeID;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Wrapping in quotes surely fix the problem! Based on your second sentence, how do I even define/initialize it if I wanted to?

Comment: You can add a null check and set a default value if needed. See the updated answer